# Come back to previous controller without 'click' on iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

Here I am, On my iOS App ( running with swift), ON click of a button in my 'details controller', It bring me to a new 'video controller' with a video playing fullscreen by default.

On closing the video, It bring back the user to this new 'video controller'.

I'd like instead to bring back the user to the 'details controller' by default instead of this 'video controller'

Is it possible to have a segue who run automatically without any push ? Or any other solution ? How can this work ?

Thanks a lot guys !

-- EDIT this is the code of my 'video controller'

```
 import UIKit
 import FirebaseAuth
 import FirebaseDatabase
 import FirebaseStorage
 import SwiftKeychainWrapper
 import SwiftyJSON

 class VideoController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var imageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var videoLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var videoVRView: GVRVideoView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageVRView: GVRPanoramaView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!


enum Media {

    static var photoArray = ["test.jpg"]

}


var currentView: UIView?
var currentDisplayMode = GVRWidgetDisplayMode.fullscreenVR
var isPaused = true
var isstop = true


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    imageLabel.isHidden = true
    imageVRView.isHidden = true
    videoLabel.isHidden = true
    videoVRView.isHidden = true

    imageVRView.load(UIImage(named: Media.photoArray.first!),
                     of: GVRPanoramaImageType.mono)
    imageVRView.enableCardboardButton = true

    videoVRView.load(from: URL(string: "\(posts[selectedIndexPath].link)"))
    videoVRView.enableCardboardButton = true
    videoVRView.enableFullscreenButton = true
    videoVRView.delegate = self
    videoVRView.displayMode = GVRWidgetDisplayMode.fullscreen
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.isSelectable = false
    titleLabel.isEditable = false
    titleLabel.isSelectable = false


    textView.text = posts[selectedIndexPath].caption
    titleLabel.text = posts[selectedIndexPath].title

    Storage.getImage(with: posts[selectedIndexPath].imageDetails){
        postPic in
        self.imageView.image = postPic

    }

}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}




@IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}



func refreshVideoPlayStatus() {
    if currentView == videoVRView && currentDisplayMode != GVRWidgetDisplayMode.embedded {
        videoVRView?.resume()
        isPaused = false
    } else {
        videoVRView?.pause()
        isPaused = true
    }
}

func setCurrentViewFromTouch(touchPoint point:CGPoint) {
    if imageVRView!.frame.contains(point) {
        currentView = imageVRView
    } else  if videoVRView!.frame.contains(point) {
        currentView = videoVRView
    }
}
}

extension VideoController: GVRWidgetViewDelegate {
 func widgetView(_ widgetView: GVRWidgetView!, didLoadContent content: Any!) {
    if content is UIImage {
        imageVRView.isHidden = false
        imageLabel.isHidden = false
    } else if content is NSURL {
        videoVRView.isHidden = true
        videoLabel.isHidden = false
        refreshVideoPlayStatus()

    }
 }

 func widgetView(_ widgetView: GVRWidgetView!, didFailToLoadContent content: Any!, withErrorMessage errorMessage: String!)  {
    print(errorMessage)
 }

 func widgetView(_ widgetView: GVRWidgetView!, didChange displayMode: GVRWidgetDisplayMode) {
    currentView = widgetView
    currentDisplayMode = displayMode
    refreshVideoPlayStatus()
    if currentView == imageVRView && currentDisplayMode != GVRWidgetDisplayMode.embedded {
        view.isHidden = true
    } else {
        view.isHidden = false
    }
 }

func widgetViewDidTap(_ widgetView: GVRWidgetView!) {
    guard currentDisplayMode != GVRWidgetDisplayMode.embedded else {return}
    if currentView == imageVRView {
        Media.photoArray.append(Media.photoArray.removeFirst())
        imageVRView?.load(UIImage(named: Media.photoArray.first!), of: GVRPanoramaImageType.mono)
    } else {
        if isPaused {
            videoVRView?.resume()
        } else {
            videoVRView?.pause()
        }
        isPaused = !isPaused
    }
}
```

}

```
 extension VideoController: GVRVideoViewDelegate {
func videoView(_ videoView: GVRVideoView!, didUpdatePosition position: TimeInterval) {
    if currentView == videoVRView && currentDisplayMode != GVRWidgetDisplayMode.embedded {
        videoVRView?.resume()
        isPaused = false
    } else {
        videoVRView?.pause()
        isPaused = true
    }
}
func videotwoView(_ videoView: GVRVideoView!, didUpdatePosition position: TimeInterval) {
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation() {
        if position >= videoView.duration() {
            videoView.seek(to: 0)
            videoView.resume()
        }
    }
}

 }


 class TouchVideoView: UIView {
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    if let VideoController = viewController() as? VideoController , event?.type == UIEventType.touches {
        VideoController.setCurrentViewFromTouch(touchPoint: point)
    }
    return true
}

func viewController() -> UIViewController? {
    if self.next!.isKind(of: VideoController.self) {
        return self.next as? UIViewController
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I am making start the video Fullscreen automatically via:

```
        videoVRView.displayMode = GVRWidgetDisplayMode.fullscreen
```

Comment: Add the code that you have used to play video.

Comment: Hi Nirav,

Thanks, I have update the code

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can . If you are using the AVPlayer to play the video you can do as

```
let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)       

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("playerDidFinishPlaying:")), 
       name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: videoPlayer.currentItem)

func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
   // call segue to move other view controller 
}
```

Comment: Hi Ram,

I have added the code, I'm using another player, GVR iOs unfortunately, do you know how could I do that ? 

Thanks @

Answer (score 0):

Register for the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification 
                                               object:nil];
```

Write code to pop to previous controller when video finish playing. after checking playbackState.

```
- (void)MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
      if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
      { //playing
      }
      if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped)
      { //stopped
      }if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)
      { //paused
      }if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted)
      { //interrupted
      }if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward)
      { //seeking forward
      }if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward)
      { //seeking backward
      }

}
```